# repeat download and pause code until download is really finished

Tags: c#, autoit

I want to make a better version of a autoit script.

So i want to download a file.
The could should pause until the file download is finished.
Sometimes the download says it is finish but it isn't. So i want to make a "loop" which repeats the download until the filesize is correct.

The AutoIt Script is:

```
Func loopdownmod()
    Local $sizefldr1 = 0
    While 1
        $sizefldr1 = DirGetSize($fldr1, 1)
If Not @error Then
    If Not $sizefldr1[1] And Not $sizefldr1[2] Then
        MsgBox(0,"i","Done.")
        Run("Explorer.exe " & $FolderPath)
        Exit
    Else
        download()
    EndIf
Else
    MsgBox(0, "i", "Error" & $fldr1)
    Exit
    EndIf
        Sleep(50)
    WEnd
EndFunc
```

I want to do this in C#.
I have a method which gets the DirectorySize of my target Folder.
I started with trying 
`while(filesize = DirSize(new DirectoryInfo(filedirectory1))´

but doesn't understand the autoit3 script to continue.

And I want to pause the Code where the file will be downloaded until the download is finish. 
Because after the download, a file have to be deleted. So I want to run the code to delete my file after download is finished. (I download with another process)

For example:
`Process.Start("MyProcess.exe");
HERE Delete Code`

Comment: Can you just use async/await to return code to the call stack once the task completes?

Comment: If you want the code to pause until the download is complete then just don't use asynchronous code? I have no idea how you are doing the download but if you say "Download this file" and then just wait for that method to return to say its done and then continue... If we could see how you are downloading the file that might help us better understand...

Comment: i editet my topic. Im downloading a file with another program. So just for the download, another program will open. and my code should be paused until the download from the other program is finished.